# HashMap cannot be cast to Entity object in Restful API netbeans+Apacheplume7

Tags: java, rest, tomee-7, netbeans-8.2

I have created a web application and added entity classes from database and then generated restful services from the entity classes. And then i have added a restful java script client and started using it. For GET/PUT method it is working as expected but for create/POST methods throwing error as 'Unable to fulfil the request'
[image]

**UsersLogin.java**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_LOGIN", catalog = "D3Common", schema = "dbo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "UsersLogin.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UsersLogin u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "UsersLogin.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM UsersLogin u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "UsersLogin.findByUserPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM UsersLogin u WHERE u.userPassword = :userPassword")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "UsersLogin.findByUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM UsersLogin u WHERE u.userName = :userName")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "UsersLogin.findByFeatureGroup", query = "SELECT u FROM UsersLogin u WHERE u.featureGroup = :featureGroup")})
public class UsersLogin implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String userId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String userPassword;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String userName;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "FEATURE_GROUP", length = 10)
    private String featureGroup;

    public UsersLogin() {
    }

    public UsersLogin(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public UsersLogin(String userId, String userPassword, String userName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getFeatureGroup() {
        return featureGroup;
    }

    public void setFeatureGroup(String featureGroup) {
        this.featureGroup = featureGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof UsersLogin)) {
            return false;
        }
        UsersLogin other = (UsersLogin) object;
        if ((this.userId == null && other.userId != null) || (this.userId != null && !this.userId.equals(other.userId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "d.UsersLogin[ userId=" + userId + " ]";
    }

}
```

**AbstarctFaced.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(filt.NewCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.class);
        resources.add(service.UsersLoginFacadeREST.class);
    }

}
```

**UsersLoginFacadeREST**

```
@Stateless //**Getting error at this line**
@Path("d.userslogin")
public class UsersLoginFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<UsersLogin> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dddPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public UsersLoginFacadeREST() {
        super(UsersLogin.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void create(UsersLogin entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") String id, UsersLogin entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public UsersLogin find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<UsersLogin> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<UsersLogin> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

**RestClient.js**

```
var app = {
    // Create this closure to contain the cached modules
    module: function () {
        // Internal module cache.
        var modules = {};

        // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
        // existing module.
        return function (name) {
            // If this module has already been created, return it.
            if (modules[name]) {
                return modules[name];
            }

            // Create a module and save it under this name
            return modules[name] = {Views: {}};
        };
    }()
};

(function (models) {

// Model for UsersLogin entity
    models.UsersLogin = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "http://localhost:8080/ddd/webresources/d.userslogin/",
        idAttribute: 'userId',
        defaults: {
            userPassword: "",
            featureGroup: "",
            userName: ""
        },
        toViewJson: function () {
            var result = this.toJSON(); // displayName property is used to render item in the list
            result.displayName = this.get('userId');
            return result;
        },
        isNew: function () {
            // default isNew() method imlementation is
            // based on the 'id' initialization which
            // sometimes is required to be initialized.
            // So isNew() is rediefined here
            return this.notSynced;
        },
        sync: function (method, model, options) {
            options || (options = {});
            var errorHandler = {
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // TODO: put your error handling code here
                    // If you use the JS client from the different domain
                    // (f.e. locally) then Cross-origin resource sharing 
                    // headers has to be set on the REST server side.
                    // Otherwise the JS client has to be copied into the
                    // some (f.e. the same) Web project on the same domain
                    alert('Unable to fulfil the request');
                }
            };

            if (method === 'create') {
                options.url = 'http://localhost:8080/ddd/webresources/d.userslogin/';
            }
            var result = Backbone.sync(method, model, _.extend(options, errorHandler));
            return result;
        }


    });


    // Collection class for UsersLogin entities
    models.UsersLoginCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: models.UsersLogin,
        url: "http://localhost:8080/ddd/webresources/d.userslogin/",
        sync: function (method, model, options) {
            options || (options = {});
            var errorHandler = {
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // TODO: put your error handling code here
                    // If you use the JS client from the different domain
                    // (f.e. locally) then Cross-origin resource sharing 
                    // headers has to be set on the REST server side.
                    // Otherwise the JS client has to be copied into the
                    // some (f.e. the same) Web project on the same domain
                    alert('Unable to fulfil the request');
                }
            };

            var result = Backbone.sync(method, model, _.extend(options, errorHandler));
            return result;
        }
    });


})(app.module("models"));

(function (views) {

    views.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tbody',
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
            var self = this;
            this.model.bind("add", function (modelName) {
                var row = new views.ListItemView({
                    model: modelName,
                    templateName: self.options.templateName
                }).render().el;
                $(self.el).append($(row));
                $(self.el).parent().trigger('addRows', [$(row)]);
            });
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            var self = this;
            _.each(this.model.models, function (modelName) {
                $(this.el).append(new views.ListItemView({
                    model: modelName,
                    templateName: self.options.templateName
                }).render().el);
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });

    views.ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        },

        template: function (json) {
            /*
             *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
             *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
             *  using jQuery 
             */
            return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        close: function () {
            var table = $(this.el).parent().parent();
            table.trigger('disable.pager');
            $(this.el).unbind();
            $(this.el).remove();
            table.trigger('enable.pager');
        }

    });

    views.ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        template: function (json) {
            /*
             *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
             *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
             *  using jQuery 
             */
            return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
        },

        /*
         *  Classes "save"  and "delete" are used on the HTML controls to listen events.
         *  So it is supposed that HTML has controls with these classes.
         */
        events: {
            "change input": "change",
            "click .save": "save",
            "click .delete": "drop"
        },

        change: function (event) {
            var target = event.target;
            console.log('changing ' + target.id + ' from: ' + target.defaultValue + ' to: ' + target.value);
        },

        save: function () {
            // TODO : put save code here
            var hash = this.options.getHashObject();
            this.model.set(hash);
            if (this.model.isNew() && this.collection) {
                var self = this;
                this.collection.create(this.model, {
                    success: function () {
                        // see isNew() method implementation in the model
                        self.model.notSynced = false;
                        self.options.navigate(self.model.id);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.model.save();
                this.model.el.parent().parent().trigger("update");
            }
            return false;
        },

        drop: function () {
            this.model.destroy({
                success: function () {
                    /*
                     *  TODO : put your code here
                     *  f.e. alert("Model is successfully deleted");
                     */
                    window.history.back();
                }
            });
            return false;
        },

        close: function () {
            $(this.el).unbind();
            $(this.el).empty();
        }
    });

    // This view is used to create new model element
    views.CreateView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.render();
        },

        render: function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
        },

        template: function (json) {
            /*
             *  templateName is element identifier in HTML
             *  $(this.options.templateName) is element access to the element
             *  using jQuery 
             */
            return _.template($(this.options.templateName).html())(json);
        },

        /*
         *  Class "new" is used on the control to listen events.
         *  So it is supposed that HTML has a control with "new" class.
         */
        events: {
            "click .new": "create"
        },

        create: function (event) {
            this.options.navigate();
            return false;
        }
    });

})(app.module("views"));


$(function () {
    var models = app.module("models");
    var views = app.module("views");

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'list',
            'new': 'create'
            ,
            ':id': 'details'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            $('#create').html(new views.CreateView({
                // tpl-create is template identifier for 'create' block
                templateName: '#tpl-create',
                navigate: function () {
                    self.navigate('new', true);
                }
            }).render().el);
        },
        list: function () {
            this.collection = new models.UsersLoginCollection();
            var self = this;
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function () {
                    self.listView = new views.ListView({
                        model: self.collection,
                        // tpl-userslogin-list-itemis template identifier for item
                        templateName: '#tpl-userslogin-list-item'
                    });
                    $('#datatable').html(self.listView.render().el).append(_.template($('#thead').html())());
                    if (self.requestedId) {
                        self.details(self.requestedId);
                    }
                    var pagerOptions = {
                        // target the pager markup 
                        container: $('.pager'),
                        // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; possiblevariables: {page}, {totalPages},{startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
                        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
                        // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
                        page: 0,
                        // Number of visible rows - default is 10
                        size: 10
                    };
                    $('#datatable').tablesorter({widthFixed: true,
                        widgets: ['zebra']}).
                            tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
                }
            });
        },
        details: function (id) {
            if (this.collection) {
                this.userslogin = this.collection.get(id);
                if (this.view) {
                    this.view.close();
                }
                var self = this;
                this.view = new views.ModelView({
                    model: this.userslogin,
                    // tpl-userslogin-details is template identifier for chosen model element
                    templateName: '#tpl-userslogin-details',
                    getHashObject: function () {
                        return self.getData();
                    }
                });
                $('#details').html(this.view.render().el);
            } else {
                this.requestedId = id;
                this.list();
            }
        },
        create: function () {
            if (this.view) {
                this.view.close();
            }
            var self = this;
            var dataModel = new models.UsersLogin();
            // see isNew() method implementation in the model
            dataModel.notSynced = true;
            this.view = new views.ModelView({
                model: dataModel,
                collection: this.collection,
                // tpl-userslogin-details is a template identifier for chosen model element
                templateName: '#tpl-userslogin-details',
                navigate: function (id) {
                    self.navigate(id, false);
                },

                getHashObject: function () {
                    return self.getData();
                }
            });
            $('#details').html(this.view.render().el);
        },
        getData: function () {
            return {
                userId: $('#userId').val(),
                userPassword: $('#userPassword').val(),
                featureGroup: $('#featureGroup').val(),
                userName: $('#userName').val()
            };
        }
    });
    new AppRouter();


    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Please help to resolve this issue